# Add another image js function

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress plugin called [User Submitted Posts](http://perishablepress.com/user-submitted-posts/).  The plugin allows for users to upload multiple photos.  I have it set up so that users can upload 0 to a max of 3.  When I try to upload more than one pic, however, only one of them gets posted.

HTML:

```
<div id="usp"> 
    <form id="usp_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""> 


        <ul id="usp_list"> 
                        <li class="usp_title"> 
                <label for="user-submitted-title" class="usp_label">Post Title</label> 
                <div> 
                    <input class="usp_input" type="text" name="user-submitted-title" id="user-submitted-title" value="" /> 
                </div> 
            </li> 
                        <li class="usp_tags"> 
                <label for="user-submitted-tags" class="usp_label">Post Tags <small>(separate tags with commas)</small></label> 
                <div> 
                    <input class="usp_input" type="text" name="user-submitted-tags" id="user-submitted-tags" value="" /> 
                </div> 
            </li> 
                        <li class="usp_content"> 
                <label for="user-submitted-content" class="usp_label">Post Content</label> 
                <div> 
                    <textarea class="usp_textarea" name="user-submitted-content" id="user-submitted-content" rows="5"></textarea> 
                </div> 
            </li> 
                                            <li class="usp_images"> 
                    <label for="user-submitted-image" class="usp_label">Upload an Image</label> 
                    <div id="usp_upload-message"></div> 
                    <div> 
                                                <input class="usp_input usp_clone" type="file" size="25" id="user-submitted-image" name="user-submitted-image[]" /> 
                                                <a href="#" id="usp_add-another">Add another image</a> 
                    </div> 
                </li> 
                                        <li class="usp_submit"> 
                                <input class="usp_input" type="submit" name="user-submitted-post" id="user-submitted-post" value="Submit Post" /> 
            </li> 
        </ul> 
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
if (!class_exists('Public_Submission_Form')) {
  class Public_Submission_Form {
    var $version = '1.0';
    var $_post_meta_IsSubmission = 'is_submission';
    var $_post_meta_Submitter    = 'user_submit_name';
    var $_post_meta_SubmitterUrl = 'user_submit_url';
    var $_post_meta_SubmitterIp  = 'user_submit_ip';
    var $_post_meta_Image        = 'user_submit_image';
    var $_post_meta_ImageInfo    = 'user_submit_image_info';
    var $settings = null;

    function Public_Submission_Form() {
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array(&$this, 'saveDefaultSettings'));
        add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'checkForSettingsSave'));
        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'addAdministrativeElements'));
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'enqueueResources'));
        add_action('parse_request', array(&$this, 'checkForPublicSubmission'));
        add_action('parse_query', array(&$this, 'addSubmittedStatusClause'));
        add_action('restrict_manage_posts', array(&$this, 'outputUserSubmissionLink'));
        add_filter('the_author', array(&$this, 'replaceAuthor'));
        add_filter('the_author_link', array(&$this, 'replaceAuthorLink'));
        add_filter('post_stati', array(&$this, 'addNewPostStatus'));
        add_shortcode('user-submitted-posts', array(&$this, 'getPublicSubmissionForm'));
    }
    function addAdministrativeElements() {
        add_options_page(__('User Submitted Posts'), __('User Submitted Posts'), 'manage_options', 'user-submitted-posts', array(&$this, 'displaySettingsPage'));
    }
    function addNewPostStatus($postStati) {
        $postStati['submitted'] = array(__('Submitted'), __('User submitted posts'), _n_noop('Submitted', 'Submitted'));
        return $postStati;
    }
    function addSubmittedStatusClause($wp_query) {
        global $pagenow;
        if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_GET['user_submitted'] == '1') {
            set_query_var('meta_key', $this->_post_meta_IsSubmission);
            set_query_var('meta_value', 1);
            set_query_var('post_status', 'pending');
        }
    }
    function checkForPublicSubmission() {
        if (isset($_POST['user-submitted-post']) && ! empty($_POST['user-submitted-post'])) {
            $settings = $this->getSettings();
            $title = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-title']);
            $content = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-content']);
            $authorName = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-name']);
            $authorUrl = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-url']);
            $tags = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-tags']);
            $category = intval($_POST['user-submitted-category']);
            $fileData = $_FILES['user-submitted-image'];
            $publicSubmission = $this->createPublicSubmission($title, $content, $authorName, $authorUrl, $tags, $category, $fileData);

            if (false == ($publicSubmission)) {
                $errorMessage = empty($settings['error-message']) ? __('An error occurred.  Please go back and try again.') : $settings['error-message'];
                if( !empty( $_POST[ 'redirect-override' ] ) ) {
                    $redirect = stripslashes( $_POST[ 'redirect-override' ] );
                    $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'submission-error' => '1' ), $redirect );
                    wp_redirect( $redirect );
                    exit();
                }
                wp_die($errorMessage);
            } else {
                $redirect = empty($settings['redirect-url']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $settings['redirect-url'];
                if (! empty($_POST['redirect-override'])) {
                    $redirect = stripslashes($_POST['redirect-override']);
                }
                $redirect = add_query_arg(array('success'=>1), $redirect);
                wp_redirect($redirect);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    function checkForSettingsSave() {
        if (isset($_POST['save-post-submission-settings']) && current_user_can('manage_options') && check_admin_referer('save-post-submission-settings')) {
            $settings = $this->getSettings();

            $settings['author'] = get_userdata($_POST['author']) ? $_POST['author'] : $settings['author'];
            $settings['categories'] = is_array($_POST['categories']) && ! empty($_POST['categories']) ? array_unique($_POST['categories']) : array(get_option('default_category'));
            $settings['number-approved'] = is_numeric($_POST['number-approved']) ? intval($_POST['number-approved']) : - 1;

            $settings['redirect-url'] = stripslashes($_POST['redirect-url']);
            $settings['error-message'] = stripslashes($_POST['error-message']);

            $settings['min-images'] = is_numeric($_POST['min-images']) ? intval($_POST['min-images']) : $settings['max-images'];
            $settings['max-images'] = (is_numeric($_POST['max-images']) && ($settings['min-images'] <= $_POST['max-images'])) ? intval($_POST['max-images']) : $settings['max-images'];

            $settings['min-image-height'] = is_numeric($_POST['min-image-height']) ? intval($_POST['min-image-height']) : $settings['min-image-height'];
            $settings['min-image-width'] = is_numeric($_POST['min-image-width']) ? intval($_POST['min-image-width']) : $settings['min-image-width'];

            $settings['max-image-height'] = (is_numeric($_POST['max-image-height']) && ($settings['min-image-height'] <= $_POST['max-image-height'])) ? intval($_POST['max-image-height']) : $settings['max-image-height'];
            $settings['max-image-width'] = (is_numeric($_POST['max-image-width']) && ($settings['min-image-width'] <= $_POST['max-image-width'])) ? intval($_POST['max-image-width']) : $settings['max-image-width'];

            $settings['usp_name'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_name']);
            $settings['usp_url'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_url']);
            $settings['usp_title'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_title']);
            $settings['usp_tags'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_tags']);
            $settings['usp_category'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_category']);
            $settings['usp_content'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_content']);
            $settings['usp_images'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_images']);

            $settings['upload-message'] = stripslashes($_POST['upload-message']);
            $settings['usp_form_width'] = stripslashes($_POST['usp_form_width']);

            $this->saveSettings($settings);
            wp_redirect(admin_url('options-general.php?page=user-submitted-posts&updated=1'));
        }
    }
    function displaySettingsPage() {
        include ('views/settings.php');
    }
    function enqueueResources() {
        wp_enqueue_script('usp_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/resources/user-submitted-posts.js', array('jquery'), $this->version);
        wp_enqueue_style('usp_style', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/resources/user-submitted-posts.css', false, $this->version, 'screen');
    }
    function getPublicSubmissionForm($atts = array(), $content = null) {
        if ($atts === true) {
            $redirect = $this->currentPageURL();
        }
        ob_start();
        include (WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/views/submission-form.php');
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    function outputUserSubmissionLink() {
        global $pagenow;
        if ($pagenow == 'edit.php') {
            echo '<a id="usp_admin_filter_posts" class="button-secondary" href="'.admin_url('edit.php?post_status=pending&amp;user_submitted=1').'">'.__('User Submitted Posts').'</a>';
        }
    }
    function replaceAuthor($author) {
        global $post;
        $isSubmission = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->_post_meta_IsSubmission, true);
        $submissionAuthor = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->_post_meta_Submitter, true);
        if ($isSubmission && ! empty($submissionAuthor)) {
            return $submissionAuthor;
        } else {
            return $author;
        }
    }
    function replaceAuthorLink($authorLink) {
        global $post;
        $isSubmission = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->_post_meta_IsSubmission, true);
        $submissionAuthor = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->_post_meta_Submitter, true);
        $submissionLink = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->_post_meta_SubmitterUrl, true);
        if ($isSubmission && ! empty($submissionAuthor)) {
            if ( empty($submissionLink)) {
                return $submissionAuthor;
            } else {
                return "<a href='{$submissionLink}'>{$submissionAuthor}</a>";
            }
        } else {
            return $authorLink;
        }
    }
    function saveDefaultSettings() {
        $settings = $this->getSettings();
        if ( empty($settings)) {
            $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

            $settings = array();
            $settings['author'] = $currentUser->ID;
            $settings['categories'] = array(get_option('default_category'));
            $settings['number-approved'] = -1;

            $settings['redirect-url'] = ''; //site_url();
            $settings['error-message'] = __('There was an error. Please ensure that you have added a title, some content, and that you have uploaded only images.');

            $settings['min-images'] = 0;
            $settings['max-images'] = 1;

            $settings['min-image-height'] = 0;
            $settings['min-image-width'] = 0;

            $settings['max-image-height'] = 500;
            $settings['max-image-width'] = 500;

            $settings['usp_name'] = 'show';
            $settings['usp_url'] = 'show';
            $settings['usp_title'] = 'show';
            $settings['usp_tags'] = 'show';
            $settings['usp_category'] = 'show';
            $settings['usp_content'] = 'show';
            $settings['usp_images'] = 'hide';

            $settings['upload-message'] = ''; // 'Please select your image(s) to upload:';
            $settings['usp_form_width'] = '300'; // in pixels

            $this->saveSettings($settings);
        }
    }
    function getSettings() {
        if ($this->settings === null) {
            $defaults = array();
            $this->settings = get_option('User Submitted Posts Settings', array());
        }
        return $this->settings;
    }
    function saveSettings($settings) {
        if (!is_array($settings)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->settings = $settings;
        update_option('User Submitted Posts Settings', $this->settings);
    }
    function createPublicSubmission($title, $content, $authorName, $authorUrl, $tags, $category, $fileData) {
        $settings = $this->getSettings();
        $authorName = strip_tags($authorName);
        $authorUrl = strip_tags($authorUrl);
        $authorIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if (!$this->validateTitle($title)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->validateContent($title)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->validateTags($tags)) {
            return false;
        }
        $postData = array();
        $postData['post_title'] = $title;
        $postData['post_content'] = $content;
        $postData['post_status'] = 'pending';
        $postData['author'] = $settings['author'];
        $numberApproved = $settings['number-approved'];

        if ($numberApproved < 0) {} elseif ($numberApproved == 0) {
            $postData['post_status'] = 'publish';
        } else {
            $posts = get_posts(array('post_status'=>'publish', 'meta_key'=>$this->_post_meta_Submitter, 'meta_value'=>$authorName));
            $counter = 0;
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                $submitterUrl = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->_post_meta_SubmitterUrl, true);
                $submitterIp = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->_post_meta_SubmitterIp, true);
                if ($submitterUrl == $authorUrl && $submitterIp == $authorIp) {
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            if ($counter >= $numberApproved) {
                $postData['post_status'] = 'publish';
            }
        }
        $newPost = wp_insert_post($postData);

        if ($newPost) {
            wp_set_post_tags($newPost, $tags);
            wp_set_post_categories($newPost, array($category));

        if (!function_exists('media_handle_upload')) {
            require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
            require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
            require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        }
        $attachmentIds = array();
        $imageCounter = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fileData['name']); $i++) {
            $imageInfo = getimagesize($fileData['tmp_name'][$i]);
            if (false === $imageInfo || !$this->imageIsRightSize($imageInfo[0], $imageInfo[1])) {
                continue;
            }
            $key = "public-submission-attachment-{$i}";
            $_FILES[$key] = array();
            $_FILES[$key]['name'] = $fileData['name'][$i];
            $_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'] = $fileData['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES[$key]['type'] = $fileData['type'][$i];
            $_FILES[$key]['error'] = $fileData['error'][$i];
            $_FILES[$key]['size'] = $fileData['size'][$i];
            $attachmentId = media_handle_upload($key, $newPost);

            if (!is_wp_error($attachmentId) && wp_attachment_is_image($attachmentId)) {
                $attachmentIds[] = $attachmentId;
                add_post_meta($newPost, $this->_post_meta_Image, wp_get_attachment_url($attachmentId));
                $imageCounter++;
            } else {
                wp_delete_attachment($attachmentId);
            }
            if ($imageCounter == $settings['max-images']) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count($attachmentIds) < $settings['min-images']) {
            foreach ($attachmentIds as $idToDelete) {
                wp_delete_attachment($idToDelete);
            }
            wp_delete_post($newPost);
            return false;
        }
        update_post_meta($newPost, $this->_post_meta_IsSubmission, true);
        update_post_meta($newPost, $this->_post_meta_Submitter, htmlentities(($authorName)));
        update_post_meta($newPost, $this->_post_meta_SubmitterUrl, htmlentities(($authorUrl)));
        update_post_meta($newPost, $this->_post_meta_SubmitterIp, $authorIp);
    }
    return $newPost;
}
function imageIsRightSize($width, $height) {
    $settings = $this->getSettings();
    $widthFits = ($width <= intval($settings['max-image-width'])) && ($width >= $settings['min-image-width']);
    $heightFits = ($height <= $settings['max-image-height']) && ($height >= $settings['min-image-height']);
    return $widthFits && $heightFits;
    }
    function validateContent($content) {
        return ! empty($content);
    }
    function validateTags($tags) {
        return true;
    }
    function validateTitle($title) {
        return ! empty($title);
    }
    function currentPageURL() {
        $pageURL = 'http';
        if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
            $pageURL .= "s";
        }
        $pageURL .= "://";
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } else {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $pageURL;
    }
}
  $publicSubmissionForm = new Public_Submission_Form();
  include ('library/template-tags.php');
}
```

== Template Tags ==

To display the images attached to user-submitted posts, use this template tag:

`<?php post_attachments(); ?>`

This template tag prints the URLs for all post attachments and accepts the following paramters:

`<?php post_attachments($size, $beforeUrl, $afterUrl, $numberImages, $postId); ?>`

`$size         = image size as thumbnail, medium, large or full -> default = full`
`$beforeUrl    = text/markup displayed before the image URL     -> default = <img src="`
`$afterUrl     = text/markup displayed after the image URL      -> default = " />`
`$numberImages = the number of images to display for each post  -> default = false (display all)`
`$postId       = an optional post ID to use                     -> default = uses global post`

Additionally, the following template tag returns an array of URLs for the specified post image:

`<?php get_post_images(); ?>`

This tag returns a boolean value indicating whether the specified post is a public submission:

`<?php is_public_submission(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `var_dump($_FILES)` look like? It looks like you're generating a unique field name for each file upload field, using `$key = "public-submission-attachment-{$i}";`. if that's the case, then your file access structure is incorrect. PHP will generate the $_FILES data for each fieldname 1 of 2 ways:

1. If you're using a unique `somestring` field name, you get a structure like:

   ```
   $_FILES['somestring'] = array(
      'name' => 'somefile.txt',
      'type' => 'text/plain',
      'size' => 1234,
      'error' => 0,
      'tmp_name'] => '/tmp/asdfasdfasdfa'
   );
   ```
2. If you're using the PHP-centric array notation, `somestring[]` (note the `[]`) for the field name, you get:

   ```
   $_FILES['somestring'] = array(
      'name' => array(
           0 => 'somefile1.txt',
           1 => 'somepic.jpg'
      ),
      'type' => array(
           0 => 'text/plain',
           1 => 'image.jpeg'
      )
      etc...
   );
   ```

Given that it you seem to be generating a unique field name, WITHOUT the array notation, you'd have to use option #1.

Comment: thanks.  I've editted my question to show the entire code, hopefully you can help me with `$_FILES`.

Comment: it'd be more useful to see what the HTML looks like, as well as a `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: OK, HTML has been added.  I'm sorry, but I'm not sure where to find `var_dump($_FILES)`, it doesn't seem to exist in any of the plugin's code...

Comment: it'd be something you add yourself. it'll dump out the contents of the $_FILES superglobal in readable format.

Comment: Gosh, I haven't "added" anything - It's a plugin.  All I've done is config it and test it.  Any suggestions, based on what's available above, on what to add to make this thing possible?  Greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: No idea. Put the var_dump line into that code, do a file upload test, and see what's output.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but according to the plugins homepage, it displays images using WordPress' `<?php get_post_images(); ?>`.  Looks like functionality should look something like http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php?

Comment: You still there?  I've editted the question again to include and excerpt from the readme.txt.  Really, I'm not a fantastic programmer (if you couldn't tell), so I'm hoping that you or someone can use this information to shed light on why this isn't working based on this information.